# linked list in C. Can't add element at the end

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Hello here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct data{
    int a;
    struct data *p;
}data;

void add(data *begin, data *new);

int main(void){
    data *first = malloc(sizeof(data));
    data *second = malloc(sizeof(data));
    data *third = malloc(sizeof(data));
    first->a = 1;
    first->p = second;
    second->a = 2;
    second->p = third;
    third->a = 3;
    third->p = NULL;
    data *new = malloc(sizeof(data));
    new->a = 4;
    add(first, new);
    data *temp = first;
    do{
        printf("%i\n", temp->a);
        temp = temp->p;
    }
    while(temp->p != NULL);
    return 0;
}

void add(data *begin, data *new){
     data *temp = malloc(sizeof(data));
     temp = begin;
     while(1){
        if(temp->p == NULL){
            temp->p = new;
            break;
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->p;
        }
     }
}
```

The code is simple. But when I run it I always get 3 (it doesn't add the new list). Please help me, I was unable to find similar question, that can help me.

Comment: I hope you are working in c; in c++ "new" is a reserved key word; it is not a wise naming choice...

Comment: Yes I'm working with C, check the libs that I include(stdio and stdlib).

Comment: new is not a wise naming choice in oldschool c, either, imho. also, can you explain why you malloc in add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines:

```
 data *temp = malloc(sizeof(data));
 temp = begin;
```

Are wrong for 1 thing, cause you first allocate memory and then don't use it. You should initialize the `temp` variable like `data *temp = NULL;`.

Then this is why you're only getting the first 3 items:

```
do{
    printf("%i\n", temp->a);
    temp = temp->p;
}
while(temp->p != NULL);
```

Your loop stops when an item has no next item (so it stops too early).

Instead, do something like this:

```
do {
    printf("%i\n", temp->a);
    temp = temp->p;
} while(temp != NULL);
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between your and my do-while loop. Only that while is on the same line that the do loop ends, but I copy it and it worked. Could you explain why?

Comment: It may be more apparent if you use a simple `while` loop instead of a `do` loop.  In your code, you terminate when the node you are on has a `NULL` `next`, before you print it.  So, the tail never gets printed.  In the new code, you terminate when `temp` is `NULL`, which happens after you printed the tail.